# How print ip with iftop sorted by bandwidth usage

Tags: linux, shell, iftop

How I can print the list of IP addresses from `iftop` output sorted by bandwidth usage?

Comment: Isn't the default behavior of `iftop` to order by traffic usage?

Answer (score 0):

From [man](https://manned.org/iftop) page of `iftop`:

> **DISPLAY ORDER**
>
> By default, the display is ordered according to the 10s average (2nd column). 
> By pressing <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> or <kbd>3</kbd> it is possible to sort by the 1st, 2nd or 3rd column.  By pressing <kbd><</kbd> or <kbd>></kbd>
> the display will be sorted by source or destination hostname respectively.

Also you can see what every column shows:

> **sort:** *(2s|10s|40s|source|destination)*
>
>   Sets which column is used to sort the display.

Comment: Please explain the second part of your answer.

Comment: 1st column shows last 2 seconds traffic, 2nd 10 seconds and so on... Pretty straightforward I think. That's why I didn't write anything else.